# NPE while creating Android Emulator on Apple M1

Tags: android, emulation, apple-m1

I'm trying to create Android Emulator on Apple M1 Max computer. Each time it crashes with NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.tools.idea.devicemanager.virtualtab.BuildVirtualDeviceConfigurationWizardActionListener.actionPerformed(BuildVirtualDeviceConfigurationWizardActionListener.java:45)
at com.intellij.util.ui.StatusText$1.onClick(StatusText.java:79)
at com.intellij.ui.ClickListener$1.mouseReleased(ClickListener.java:59)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
at com.intellij.ui.table.JBTable.processMouseEvent(JBTable.java:764)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2790)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:820)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:498)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

**My setup:**

- Android Studio 2021.3.1 Patch 1
- MacOS 12.6.1
- Chip Apple M1 MAX, 64GB RAM

**What I tried:**
I tried creating different system images (Tiramisu, S, R - always ARM, I tried images with and without Google API). I tried creating devices with and without Play Store.
I also tried to create an emulator using command line tool `./avdmanager create avd -f -n "emulator" -d 25 -k 'system-images;android-31;default;arm64-v8a'` - each time it fails with emulator creation.

Answer (score 0):

After few days I managed to find an answer.
Additional to emulator creation issues, I also couldn't connect to any Android  device. When I run `adb devices`, phone was discovered but always was `unanutorized`.

The reason was that I have a company IT managed computer, and most of a setup was done before it was delivered to me. And the issue was that my user didn't had an access to `~/.android` directory...

So I had to request admin rights and then I was able to execute `sudo chmod -R 777 .android`, that solved all my issues.